# How to write from a PySpark DStream to Redis?

Tags: python, apache-spark, redis, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am using PySpark 2.3.1 to read a stream of values from Kafka as `DStream`s. I want to do some transforms on this data, like take a moving average, and save it to Redis. My spark job code looks a bit like this:

```
batch_duration = 1

# Initialize session
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("my-app") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark_context = spark_session.sparkContext

# Create streaming context (=connection to Spark)
streaming_context = StreamingContext(spark_context, batch_duration)

# Read from Kafka
input = KafkaUtils \
    .createDirectStream(streaming_context, ['price'], {"metadata.broker.list": kafka_urls})
```

I can then transform it with lines like:

```
jsons = input.window(5000).map(lambda t: t[1]).map(json.loads)
prices = jsons.map(lambda d: d['price'])
total = prices.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

However `total` in this case is still a `DStream`, and the [documentation for Redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/python.md) says that only Dataframes can be written from PySpark. Fortunately, `DStream` produces periodic RDD's as it runs - so I have to figure out how to convert the RDD to a Dataframe.

I tried

```
total.foreachRDD(lambda rdd:
                 rdd.toDF().write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis") \
                 .option("table", "people") \
                 .option("key.column", "name") \
                 .save())
```

Admittedly this was copied and pasted blindly from elsewhere on the net, so the `option` calls almost certainly don't match my data schema. I was hoping to decipher the exceptions and figure out where to go next. Unfortunately running this on my Spark cluster prints many lines of Java stack traces, and scrolls the original Python exception outside of my console history, so I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Word Counter example that saves result to Redis:

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

def save_rdd(rdd):
    if not rdd.isEmpty():
        df = rdd.toDF()
        df.show()
        df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "counts").option("key.column", "_1").save(mode='append')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Example") \
        .getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

    counts.foreachRDD(save_rdd)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Submit command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://Oleksiis-MacBook-Pro.local:7077 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0,com.redislabs:spark-redis:2.4.0 ~/Projects/spark-redis-test/src/main/scala/com/redislabs/provider/test/spark-direct-kafka.py localhost:9092 new_topic
```

Please note that I included `com.redislabs:spark-redis:2.4.0` package.

Write some words to `new_topic`:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic new_topic

>a b c a
>a b b
```

The output should appear in Redis as hashes where the key corresponds to the input word:

```
./redis-cli

keys counts:*

1) "counts:a"
2) "counts:b"
3) "counts:c"

127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall counts:a
1) "_2"
2) "2"
```

If you'd like to save DataFrame with some meaningful column names rather than `_1`, `_2`, etc - you can rename columns like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def save_rdd(rdd):
    if not rdd.isEmpty():
        df = rdd.toDF().select(col("_1").alias("word"), col("_2").alias("count"))
        df.show()
        df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "counts").option("key.column","word").save(mode='append')
```

Note that now we set `key.coumn` parameter to be `word`.

Now the field name in Redis is "count":

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall counts:abc
1) "count"
2) "1"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried to use only your `save_rdd` function in my own code - if the datastream is empty it prints output and doesn't crash, but I see no table in redis. If the stream is not empty I get `raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row)) TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'float'>`

Comment: @Wassinger, it looks like in your example the RDD contains a single value - sum of all prices. What should be the key of the Redis hash for this value? Most likely in your example `rdd.toDF()` fails, you can fix it with `df = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF()`, but the DF will contain a single column with the value, how do you want to query it later? Just for testing - you can save it with auto-generated key using `df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "counts").save(mode='append')`.